# Read from text file C++ (fname, lname, class, seat number), store and verify

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file

I have a text file of the classlook like this:

```
FName LName Class SeatNum
FName2 LName2 Class2 SeatNum2
...
```

and the list goes on.

How to read lines of strings and store them into different variables?
How to combine Class & SeatNum to be an ID (3D-20)?
How to verify for every input name and ID has to be matched?
For example, input > FName LName Class2-SeatNum2 is wrong, please try again.

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: We don't do homeworks

Comment: @P0W Not really. We don't do trivial homeworks showing lack of research effort and understanding of fundamental language principles. Actually `s/homeworks/problems/`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note for next time - because you didn't detail the problem, it was hard to figure out what you mean. Anyhow:

in order to do what you asked you need to:

**a)** read the data from the file

**b)** split the data based on the character which is between the cells.

In C++, The split string algorithm is in boost - if you dont know what that is, make sure you take a look in here: http://www.boost.org/

**Soltion**:
*I`m modifying various cPlusPlus guides here to fit your purpouse:*

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
using namespace std;

vector<string> getData (string filePath) {
  vector<string> Cells; // In the end, here we will store each cell's content.
  stringstream fileContent(""); // This is a string stream, which will store the database as a string.
  ofstream myfile; // the file which the database is in
  myfile.open (filePath); // Opening the file
  while ( getline (myfile,line) ) // Reading it until it's over
  {
  fileContent << line;  // adding each line to the string
  }
  split(Cells, fileContent.str(), is_any_of(" "));// Here, insert the char which seperates the cells from each other.
  myfile.close()
  return Cells; // returning the split string.
}
```

Hope i helped :)

Comment: neat solution but your includes are not displayed

Comment: Editted; Also, I added a few comments on the way :)